# C#: Argument validation: null/empty strings

Tags: c#, string, argument-validation

I don't know how many countless times I've had to write code to validate string arguments:

```
public RoomName(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be empty", "name");
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to avoid this? Is there some attribute or design-by-contract mechanism to avoid this? Is there no way to say:

```
public RoomName(NotNullOrEmptyString name)
{
```

without having to actually create that type?

Comment: You might find this link on [Argument validation using attributes and method interception](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/argument-validation-using-attributes.html) useful

Answer (score 7):

You can do that via code injection with attributes.

Another option to save some coding time, but still give you a lot of control, would be to use something like [CuttingEdge.Conditions](http://www.codeplex.com/conditions).  This provides a fluent interface for argument checking, so you can write:

```
name.Requires().IsNotNull();
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the question has been answered a while ago, I have been thinking about the same problem lately. Formalized code contracts (with automatic verification or checks) seem to be a good idea, but generally, their verification-capability is quite limited, and for simple checks like null- or empty-string checking, they require just as much code (or more) than the old-fashioned checks.

Ironically, the best answer in my opinion for the string-case is indeed one or two classes that wrap a string that has been checked not to be null, empty or white-space, and pass this instance around:

```
public class NonEmptyString : IComparable<NonEmptyString>, ...
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public NonEmptyString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        if (value.Length == 0)
        {                
            throw NewStringIsEmptyException("value");
        }
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    ...
}

public class NonWhiteSpaceString : NonEmptyString
{
    ....
}
```

Sure, passing around these instances does not prevent you from having to check if they are null themselves, but it's got some big advantages:

- You don't have to check on empty or white-space strings over and over again, which can be error prone in situations where the string is passed around a lot.
- As I have done in my implementation, checking for null is something different than checking for an empty value (or whitespace value), because you want to throw a specific ArgumentNullException in the former case, and some ArgumentException in the second.
- It clearly signals the constraint on the value of the string, just like any wrapping class is supposed to do. In fact, if you have a string that has any constraints and it is passed around a lot, I always recommend to wrap it in a class that encapsulates the check and keeps the rest of the code out of trouble. A good example of this are strings that must satisfy a certain regular expression. However, I'm diverting from the question here...

Comment: I think you need to add some tracking of the parameter name to your solution. This is because most would find it confusing if you called `frob(string foo, string bar)` with `frob(null, "a value")` and got the error message `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value` instead of `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: foo`

Answer (score 0):

See also [C#: How to Implement and use a NotNull and CanBeNull attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792531/c-how-to-implement-and-use-a-notnull-and-canbenull-attribute) for more information on Code Contracts, how they can be implemented today in VS2008, and how they will be integrated into VS2010.